# Could not load file or assembly WebMarkupMin.Core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have installed

> WebMarkupMin.MVC

using nuget on my visual studio 2013 MVC project.

Now this installed with no error whatsoever, however when I run the solution i get the following error;

> Could not load file or assembly 'WebMarkupMin.Core, Version=1.1.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=99472178d266584b' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Now checking the reference of the dll in the solution (ie. right click properties) shows version 1.0.0.0, with runtime version v4.0.30319.

My web.config has the following;

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="WebMarkupMin.Core" publicKeyToken="99472178d266584b" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.0.0.0" newVersion="1.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

and my packages.config has the following;

```
  <package id="WebMarkupMin.Core" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="WebMarkupMin.Mvc" version="1.1.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="WebMarkupMin.Web" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net451" />
```

I have cleaned the solution and deleted all files in the bin folder, rebuilt and re-ran the project but still get the same error?

For completeness I then use the WebMarkupMin as follows in my MVC Controller;

```
using WebMarkupMin.Mvc.ActionFilters;
namespace MyProject.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {

        [MinifyHtml]
        [OutputCache(Duration = 4956, VaryByParam = "none")]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

Is there something I am missing here, any ideas why its referencing the 1.1.0 version?

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve this by specifying the .Core version through Nuget to be 1.1.0.0

> install-package WebMarkupMin.Core -version 1.1.0.0

I'm not sure if this is specific to my issue, but hopefully it helps someone else.

Answer (score 2):

Change settings in `Web.config` file as follows:

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="WebMarkupMin.Core" publicKeyToken="99472178d266584b" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```